# Python Requests for NewsAPI reponding 401 every time

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to use the [News API](https://newsapi.org/) in a python program, and for some reason I can't get a 200 response no matter what. I'm pretty unfamiliar with the requests library, so maybe I'm not doing something right, but here's what my code looks like:

```
api = XXXXXXXXXX

def get_json_response(apiKey, resource='google-news', sortBy='latest'):
    url = 'https://newsapi.org/v1/articles'
    headers = { 'source': resource,
                'apiKey': apiKey,
                'sortBy': sortBy}

    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    print(r.status_code)

get_json_response(api)
```

and the output is always 401. 
But what's weird is if i just put "https://newsapi.org/v1/articles/?source=google-news&apiKey=XXXXXXXXX" in a browser, it gives the correct json response, so it has to be something wrong with how I'm using requests.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

EDIT:
Not exactly an elegant solution, but i switched the line to:

```
r = requests.get(url + '/?source=' + resource + '&sortBy=' + sortBy + '&apiKey=' + apiKey)
```

And that worked, but I'd still like to know how to use the requests package correctly for the future.

Comment: just noticed google news doesn't allow sorting by latest, but even with that removed, the problem remains

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the 'working' link provided, it expects URL parameters, not headers on its request, so:

```
def get_json_response(apiKey, resource='google-news'):
    url = 'https://newsapi.org/v1/articles/'
    params = {'source': resource,
              'apiKey': apiKey}
    r = requests.get(url, params=params)
    print(r.status_code)
    # etc.
```

Comment: You can actually send the API key as an 'x-api-key' header, but that is the only one as far as I'm aware.